# Duplicate word frequencies issues in Java

Tags: java, file, text

[I am new to Java and Stackoverflow. My last question was closed. I have added a complete code this time. thanks] I have a large txt file of 4GB (*vocab.txt*). It contains plain Bangla(unicode) words. Each word is in *newline* with its frequency(equal sign in between). Such as,

```
আমার=5 
তুমি=3
সে=4 
আমার=3 //duplicate of 1st word of with different frequency
করিম=8 
সে=7    //duplicate of 3rd word of with different frequency
```

As you can see, it has same words multiple times with different frequencies. How to keep only a single word (instead of multiple duplicates) and with summation of all frequencies of the duplicate words. Such as, the file above would be like (*output.txt*),

```
আমার=8   //5+3
তুমি=3
সে=11      //4+7
করিম=8
```

I have used HashMap to solve the problem. But I think I made some mistakes somewhere. It runs and shows the exact data to output file without changing anything.

```
package data_correction;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            Scanner sc = null;
            String path="C:\\DATA\\vocab.txt";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\DATA\\output.txt",true);
            
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF-8"));
            try {
                System.out.println("Started!!");
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
                sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = sc.nextLine();
                        line = line.trim();
                        String [] arr = line.split("=");
                        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
                            if (!map.containsKey(arr[0])){
                                 map.put(arr[0],Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                            } 
                            else{
                                 map.put(arr[0], map.get(arr[0]) + Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                            }

                            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> each : map.entrySet()){
                                bufferedWriter.write(each.getKey()+"="+each.getValue()+"\n"); 
                            }

                }
                bufferedWriter.close();
                if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                    throw sc.ioException();
                }
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (sc != null) {
                    sc.close();
                }
            }
            System.out.print("FINISH");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The for loop where you write to the BufferedWriter looks like it is running for each line read. Should that be outside the loop?

Comment: Exactly. sorry my mistake.

Comment: @AndyTurner I take out the for loop and the map declaration out of the while loop. But now it is showing Array index out of bound exception and I don't know why.

Comment: That exception would occur if there is some line with no equals sign, so that when you split, you don't get two strings. You should check your input (there may be blank lines, possibly at the beginning or end), and in the code, you should check that the length of the array after you split is 2, and if not, either skip that line, or print a warning message.

Comment: Be aware that with a HashMap the order of the output will be unpredictable. If you want it to follow the input order (as closely as possible, since there are duplicates), you can use a LinkedHashMap, and if you want the output to be sorted, you can get a list of the keys and sort them, or, of course, sort the file afterwards, separately.

Comment: The same exercise as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198617/duplicate-word-frequencies-problem-in-text-file-in-java

Comment: Do not repost questions. Edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want with some mor eJava magic:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String separator = "=";
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        try (Stream<String> vocabs = Files.lines(new File("test.txt").toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            vocabs.forEach(
                    vocab -> {
                        String[] pair = vocab.split(separator);
                        int value = Integer.valueOf(pair[1]);
                        String key = pair[0];
                        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                            map.put(key, map.get(key) + value);
                        } else {
                            map.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

For `test.txt` take the correct file path. Pay attention that the map is kept in memory, so this is maybe not the best approach. If necessary replace the map with a e.g. database backed approach.